# Duplicated rows (x) amount of times in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦
║      SO  ║   SO_Line ║  ...   ║ 
╠══════════╬═══════════╣════════║
║      ABC ║        1  ║        ║
║      ABC ║        3  ║        ║
║      ABC ║        5  ║        ║
║      DEF ║        1  ║        ║
║      DEF ║        2  ║        ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╝════════╝
```

What I'd like to do is duplicate a result set (x) amount of times.  For instance, given this result set: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE SO = 'ABC'`, I'd like to duplicate that result set 10 times.  Basically I want to keep all of the data in all of the other columns the same, but I'll change the primary key to be something else (for instance, `ABC-1`).  My final table after duplicating that set would be like this:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦
║      SO  ║   SO_Line ║  ...   ║ 
╠══════════╬═══════════╣════════║
║      ABC ║        1  ║  ...   ║
║      ABC ║        3  ║  ...   ║
║      ABC ║        5  ║  ...   ║
║    ABC-1 ║        1  ║  ...   ║
║    ABC-1 ║        3  ║  ...   ║
║    ABC-1 ║        5  ║  ...   ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╝════════╝
```

Normally the way I would do this is by inserting the records from the result set into a temporary table and then assigning a row number to each row.  Then I'd iterate through the temporary table using something like `WHILE @i < @RowCount` and do an insert into the main table using `@i` to increment the PK.  I'm basically asking if A) that's the most reasonable way to accomplish this, and if not, B) is there a more efficient way of handling this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it using a [table value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) or a value list, and a [CROSS JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx).

> ```
> INSERT INTO foo
> SELECT CONCAT(SO, t.x) as SO, SO_Line
> FROM   foo
> CROSS JOIN (VALUES('-1'),('-2'),('-3'),('-4'),('-5')) t(x)
> WHERE  SO = 'ABC';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 15 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM   foo;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> SO    | SO_Line
> :---- | ------:
> ABC   |       1
> ABC   |       3
> ABC   |       5
> DEF   |       1
> DEF   |       2
> ABC-1 |       1
> ABC-2 |       1
> ABC-3 |       1
> ABC-4 |       1
> ABC-5 |       1
> ABC-1 |       3
> ABC-2 |       3
> ABC-3 |       3
> ABC-4 |       3
> ABC-5 |       3
> ABC-1 |       5
> ABC-2 |       5
> ABC-3 |       5
> ABC-4 |       5
> ABC-5 |       5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=88bf221e9c8a8d97d1ca9083f486a213)*

Instead of use a value list, you could use an [INLINE User defined function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) like this:

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION tvValues(@Num int)
> RETURNS table
> AS
> RETURN 
> (
>      SELECT TOP (@Num) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.[object_id]) [item]
>      FROM    sys.all_objects S
> )
> GO
> ```

Then convert your query to:

> ```
> INSERT INTO foo
> SELECT CONCAT(SO, '-', t.item) as SO, SO_Line
> FROM   foo
> CROSS JOIN tvValues(7) t
> WHERE  SO = 'ABC';
> GO
> ```

NOTE: I've used `tvValues(7)` but you can use other values.

This is the result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM   foo;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> SO    | SO_Line
> :---- | ------:
> ABC   |       1
> ABC   |       3
> ABC   |       5
> DEF   |       1
> DEF   |       2
> ABC-1 |       1
> ABC-2 |       1
> ABC-3 |       1
> ABC-4 |       1
> ABC-5 |       1
> ABC-6 |       1
> ABC-7 |       1
> ABC-1 |       3
> ABC-2 |       3
> ABC-3 |       3
> ABC-4 |       3
> ABC-5 |       3
> ABC-6 |       3
> ABC-7 |       3
> ABC-1 |       5
> ABC-2 |       5
> ABC-3 |       5
> ABC-4 |       5
> ABC-5 |       5
> ABC-6 |       5
> ABC-7 |       5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=491d1aee4a2cb398f9773f1b07be51eb)*

Answer (score 3):

Create a table containing just a number column and insert the numbers `1 ... max`, where `max` is at least 10. Then cross join this table with the result set

```
INSERT INTO Table (SO, SO_Line, ...)
SELECT SO + '-' + CONVERT (varchar, Numbers.number), SO_Line, ...
FROM
    Table
    CROSS JOIN Numbers
WHERE Table.SO = 'ABC' AND Numbers.number <= 10
```

[CROSS JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) creates all combinations from the rows of the first and the second result set. So if you you have 3 rows of `Table` and 10 of `Numbers` you will get 3 * 10 = 30 combined resulting rows.

Note, that his allows you to easily specify a variable number of repetitions (up to `max`) by just editing the number manually, through a parameter or from a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default table in master DB

```
DECLARE @number INT = 10

INSERT INTO foo
SELECT CONCAT(SO, ' - ', CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.number + 1)) as SO, SO_Line
FROM   foo
INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v ON v.number < @number
WHERE  SO = 'ABC' AND v.[type] = 'P'


SO      |   SO_Line
-------------------
ABC     |   1
ABC     |   3
ABC     |   5
DEF     |   1
DEF     |   2
ABC - 1 |   1
ABC - 2 |   1
ABC - 3 |   1
ABC - 4 |   1
ABC - 5 |   1
ABC - 6 |   1
ABC - 7 |   1
ABC - 8 |   1
ABC - 9 |   1
ABC - 10|   1
ABC - 1 |   3
ABC - 2 |   3
ABC - 3 |   3
ABC - 4 |   3
ABC - 5 |   3
ABC - 6 |   3
ABC - 7 |   3
ABC - 8 |   3
ABC - 9 |   3
ABC - 10|   3
ABC - 1 |   5
ABC - 2 |   5
ABC - 3 |   5
ABC - 4 |   5
ABC - 5 |   5
ABC - 6 |   5
ABC - 7 |   5
ABC - 8 |   5
ABC - 9 |   5
ABC - 10|   5
```

It works for up to 2048 times repeat